# Optimal asset allocation in three-asset portfolio

Tags: capm

I apologize if similar question has been already asked.

I have to find optimal weights $w_F,_I,_M$ for the assets $F, I, M$ in the portfolio.

$E(r_F) = 0.03$

$σ_F = 0$

$E(r_I) = 0.2325$

$σ_I = 0.5$

$E(r_M) = 0.12$

$σ_M = 0.2$

$ρ_I,_M = 0.9$

After computing the $σ_p^2$, I get: $0.0225 =0.25w_I^2 + 0.04w_M^2 + 0.18w_I,_M  $

So I also know that $ w_I + w_M + w_F = 1 $, but I can't get optimal values nevertheless. Any ideas?

Comment: You could do it in two steps. (1) There are 2 risky assets, these define an efficient frontier. (2)The third asset is a risk free asset. Find the tangent from this asset to the efficient frontier. The point of tangency is the unique OCRA (optimal combination of risky assets)

Comment: I've seen this requires calculating all possible weight combinations in Excel. I have to do it on exam, so is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend having a look at [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/portfolioTheoryMatrix.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjImc7vkKjkAhVEWX0KHWWHAIcQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw1vru_RQQ2yvv6HHUVJ7Yq8) pdf, it outlines how to determine optimal weightings for n risky assets with linear algebra methods. 
The crux of the problem is that you must solve for the partial derivatives with respect to each weight, for 0 with the constraint of the sum of the weights = 1. This can be solved as a constrained optimisation problem / linear programming problem. Or, if you're looking for a quick answer, the pdf outlines a simple matrix operation to find the optimal weightings.

Hope this helps